# How to calculate mean by skipping String Value in Numeric Column?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, for-loop, functional-programming

```
Name  Emp_ID     Salary  Age
0 John   Abc     21000   31
1 mark   Abn     34000   82
2 samy   bbc     thirty  78
3 Johny  Ajc     21000   34
4 John   Ajk    2100.28  twentyone
```

How to calculate mean of 'Age' Column without changing string value in that column. Basically i want to loop through age column for numerical value and gives mean of that list of value. If any string comes it should skip that value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pd.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with the argument `errors='coerce'`, which turns values to `NaN` if it can't convert it to numeric. Then use [`Series.mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mean.html):

```
pd.to_numeric(df['Age'],errors='coerce').mean()

#Out
56.25
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But if i put errors = 'coerce' it will convert the value to NaN, but value Should not change.

Comment: What is your expected output? Because we are not overwriting your column, so the value is not changed in-place.

Comment: yeah  that's true we are not actually overwriting it. I got it thanks